# Include or extend a class/module from a gem (e.g. devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, devise

I have written a small module **lib/encryption/encryption.rb**

```
module Encryption
  def self.encrypt(value)
    ...
  end

  def self.decrypt(value)
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to use/access this module in these two files from Devise, namely:

1. **token_authenticatable.rb**
2. **authenticatable.rb**

I already have overwritten both of them by creating 2 new files and putting them into /config/initilaizers (copied the original source code within them and modified them)

1. **/config/initializers/token_authenticable.rb**
2. **/config/initializers/authenticatable.rb**

One file looks like this for instance:

```
require 'devise/strategies/token_authenticatable'
require './lib/encryption/encryption.rb' #TRIED THIS, BUT DOES NOT WORK

module Devise
  module Models
    # The TokenAuthenticatable module is responsible for generating an authentication token and
    # validating the authenticity of the same while signing in.
    ...
```

my modifications work, but how can I access my lib/Encryption.rb module within these files?
Is this modification approach best practice? 
If not, what is the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this in your application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Then '/lib' will be autoloaded. Meaning you can call

```
require 'encryption/encryption'
```

And it should work.

Comment: Thank you, this works! 
I already had added /lib to the config.autoload_paths with     `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap two methods inside a class such as MyEncryptionAlgo. Create an object of that class

```
obj = Encryption::MyEncryptionAlgo.new
```

Use this object to access those two method.

```
obj.encrypt(value)
obj.decrypt(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how do I include the module with this class  in the /config/initializers/*.rb files? (see edited question)